# How to measure the efficiency at finite sample of a skewness index?

Tags: skewness

Suppose I wanted to know which of the skewness indexes 2 to 7 listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Other_measures_of_skewness) is most precise in finite samples of fixed sizes drawn from a known *skewed* distribution.

How could I do this using simulations?

Just comparing their empirical variances won't do because they don't estimate skewness on the same scale. Normalizing the empirical variances by the mean skewness index (as is done in [0] for the case of dispersion measures) also won't do because the mean skewness could be very close to 0.

- [0] P. J. Bickel and E. L. Lehmann. Descriptive Statistics for Nonparametric Models. III. Dispersion.     Ann. Statist. Volume 4, Number 6 (1976), 1139-1158.

Comment: What do you mean by 'precise' here?

Comment: @Glen_b: Im looking for an alternative to the normalized empirical variance which is used in [0] to measure finite sample efficiency because that concept (normalized empirical variance) does not work very well for estimates of skewness (for the reasons I explained in the question)